# How to decrease the height of image logo in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I have an image logo in my website: quantgreeks.com. I would like to reduce the size of the logo length. It seems to take up a lot of space on the top. I would like to reduce that without changing the size of image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing/reducing the `padding-bottom: 45px; padding-top: 45px;` from `header#masthead hgroup` should fix that problem. 
It would then be:

```
header#masthead hgroup {
    position: relative;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

or

```
header#masthead hgroup {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 15px; Example value
    padding-top: 15px; Example value
    zoom: 1;
}
```